# Can I access COM resource like Excel, Data link dialog from silverlight page?

Tags: c#, silverlight, excel, iis, com

I have got it working as out of browser application, but I was wondering if I can directly access these resources from silverlight page and not OOB .

I guess With OOB the user install the application from the page.

When I run the silvelright 4 project from VS 2010 (WITHOUT Out Of Browser settings) , it can access all the COM resources like Excel and data link dialog. But when I deploy the silverlight application in IIS 7.0, it fails accessing the resource. No exception resported though.

So that question in 1 line is : Can i access COM resource from silverlight page (not OOB) when its deployed in IIS

thank you

Comment: according to this post ... OOB and elevated trust are different things .. so i am a little confused here http://www.lyalin.com/Blog/archive/2010/06/24/silverlight-4-ndash-in-browser-vs.-oob-elevated-trust.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access COM objects in a Silverlight 4 in browser app.  The app needs to be OOB with elevated trust.  Note an app can be OOB yet not have elevated trust that is an additional option you need to select after enabling OOB.